# How To Keep Conditional Formatting When Sorting via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that sorts a range on range change. It sorts the values but leaves the conditional formatting behind. How can I keep the conditional formatting?

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("range2rating")) Is Nothing Then
Call deadlines1
End If
End Sub

Sub deadlines1()
Range("range2").Sort _
Key1:=Range("range2rating"), Order1:=xlDescending
End Sub
```

Comment: I would look into having the code do the formatting after the sort. https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/338845-sorting-keep-cell-formatting-2.html

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? What do you expect to happen? What is NOT happening?

Comment: sorry forgot to ask the question. how do i get the code to also move the conditional formatting and the fills of the cells when it sorts?

Comment: AFAIK conditional formatting does change with sort, but depending on how you defined the range for conditional formatting, it may not change with the data range. Either (1) define the conditional formatting range dynamically, or (2) drop all conditional formatting BEFORE your script, and reapply them AFTER your script.